# Docker - run error on window git bash for -v

Tags: windows, git, bash, docker

[image: error pic]

I run docker in my win10, but use `-v` params has a error.

```
docker run --privileged=true -d --name=ubuntu14.04 -v e:/docker/data:/data ubuntu /bin/bash
```

error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash: no such file or directory".
```

When I ls this path just like [error path pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xwb.png):

[image: error path]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If possible, try the same command in a regular DOS session, instead of a git bash.

That will avoid the git bash session to automatically resolve `/bin/bash` to `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash`, which won't be known at all by the ubuntu container.

The OP confirms this is working, provided the following options are added:

```
--attach=STDIN 
--privileged=true
```

Comment: Thanks VonC,follow you suggest,i can run success,but container also can't run normally,luckly,I have add two option, the it's ok!! one is keep STDIN open even if not attached, anthor Privileged mode.that all in kitematic.

Comment: @Y.elinx Great! What was the final command you ended up with?

Comment: That should be --attach=STDIN and --privileged=true,at docker doc run param can find them,but i think is --privileged=true effect.

Comment: @Y.elinx OK. I have added those to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: `--attach=STDIN` was enough in my case, thx.

Comment: @ya_dimon Thank you for the feedback. Maybe this has changed since 2017.

Answer (score 14):

Add two slashes before `bin/sh` to turn off GitBash's automatic path conversion.

```
docker run --privileged=true -d --name=ubuntu14.04 -v e:/docker/data:/data ubuntu //bin/bash
```

or if you're trying to attach to a running container

```
docker attach -it ubuntu //bin/bash
```

Answer (score 6):

```
winpty docker run -i -t test1 ./bin/sh
```

Will work on Windows OS.

Comment: simple and useful. I just needed those point (`./bin/...`) before command. thanks